# Problem with an SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

I'm having a problem with an SQL statement. 
I want to activate a "ON UPDATE CASCADE" behavior for a foreign key in a table with this statement :

```
ALTER TABLE "DB"."RECORD" ADD CONSTRAINT "RECORD_PT_OUTIL_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("CDE_PO")
REFERENCES "DB"."PT_OUTIL" ("CDE_PO") ON UPDATE CASCADE ENABLE;
```

But when i run the statement in Oracle Developer, i just get this error message : "ORA-00905 : missing keyword"
I can't find what could be this missing keyword, i tried several changes but always the same error occurs.
I reuse a code generated by Oracle Developer it self and just modify it with what i want.
This is the generated code :

```
ALTER TABLE "DB"."RECORD" ADD CONSTRAINT "RECORD_PT_OUTIL_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("CDE_PO")
REFERENCES "DB"."PT_OUTIL" ("CDE_PO") ON DELETE CASCADE DISABLE;
```

See, i just change the end of it.
So what's the matter here ? Am i missing something ? (please don't bash if it's something obvious :) )
Thx !

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support the `ON UPDATE` clause for foreign keys.

See the description of the `REFERENCES` clause in the manual:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the `DISABLE`/ `ENABLE` at the end of your command

As per the [ADD CONSTRAINT reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), there doesnt seem to be any "Enable / Disable" as part of the command.

I think it is something that your Oracle Developer is adding at the end ([it being part of Oracle Syntax](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_add_constraint_syntax_example.htm)) and it might be causing the problem!!

Comment: I give you the DDL generated to create the Table, maybe you'll see something weird ... :

Comment: @B1ll0u - what db engine are you using in MySQL? Is the table in question using MyISAM or InnoDB?